# How to diagnostics multiple unexpected client connection/disconnection on blazor server side

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

I have an blazor server-side app deployed on average 100 site which generally works pretty well.

But for very few site, end-users complain about micro disconnection/reconnection on the app (they see the components-reconnect-modal few seconds).

I logged some information on the OnConnectionUpAsync and OnConnectionDownAsync of the CircuitHandler to see whats happen, and effectively i notice some log showing a lot of time client disconnected for one, two or three seconds. But i don't have the reason

There is an average of maybe 50 and 100 end user connected at the same time at the app on this site.

I really don't know how to start to investigate this case. This client have a server well dimensionnate, with recent windows server, the configuration is OK.

I don't have specific configuration or parameters on the app

I would suspect the problem is on the network of my client (so not specific on my app, like shutdown of the network for 3 second), but The client assure me is network works very well and he don't have any problems with his others apps.

Have you any idea what i can do to have more information on this problem ?

do you know some tools which can test the network and show potentials problems ?

thanks in advance